# LifecycleRegistryOwner deprecated explicit implementing is still needed

Tags: android, android-livedata

I can see Android Studio warning about **`LifecycleRegistryOwner`**.
In google docs I can see:
"Use `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` which extends `LifecycleOwner`, so there are no use cases for this class."
But, I use a fragment.
my fragment imported from "`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`"
I can see that this fragments already implements `LifecycleOwner`.

But, when I delete explicit implementing of **`LifecycleRegistryOwner`** interface, functionality related to LiveData stop work.
When I revert implementing interface all works fine, but I have the warning.

```
archLifecycleVersion = "1.0.0"
```

Comment: How do you deleted LifecycleRegistryOwner interface ??

Comment: @Burhanuddin Rashid. I meant deleting of explicit implementation of this interface during describing of my fragment.

Comment: Have you updated supported libraries to 26.1.0 ??

Comment: @Burhanuddin Rashid. My support library version now is 27.0.0

Comment: Can you post your code